# Disable MSVC linker warning in Qt Creator 4.8

Tags: qt, visual-c++, linker, warnings, qt-creator

What do I need to add to the .pro file in Qt Creator 4.8.0 to disable specific MSVC linker warnings (using MSVC to build, obviously)?

Specifically I want to disable linker warning 4099 (a missing PDB file that I do not have the ability to generate).

Comment: QMAKE_LFLAGS answer below is correct, thanks. It turns out you just can't disable warning 4099 in the MS linker with /ignore: http://michaelnoland.com/how-to-supress-warning-lnk4099-pdb-xxx-was-not-found/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `QMAKE_LFLAGS += /ignore:4099` to your .pro file.

Comment: Ah thanks. I had tried that and it wasn't working so I thought I got it wrong in Qt. But actually, it turns out the MS linker just specifically doesn't let you disable 4099: http://michaelnoland.com/how-to-supress-warning-lnk4099-pdb-xxx-was-not-found/ Oh well.